# How do I hide properties of a model/object dynamically when retrieving it using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

My question is more theoretical, and I would like to know how do you handle this thing hiding property of an object dynamically. I know you can use

```
`protected $hidden`
```

as an array to hide the specific attributes, but this will not work for the case that based on different context of user show different attributes of the model.

An imaginary scenario would be: Let say we have three different users on platform, super admin, admin, normal users and each of the users can see all other users but let say super admin can see all attributes of user, admin, can see all not only password, and normal user can see only specific attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set the hidden attribute of a model dynamically you can use the [`setHidden()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L2161-L2166) method on the eloquent model after querying for it from the database. This way you'll prevent it from outputting those fields by accident via lazy/eager loading.

Answer (score -1):

Thinking difference, in other framework like Moodle, they define some arrays to handle the attributes that group of users could see.

Let see a small example I write bellow, you could apply if possible:

```
$attrSuperAdmin   = ['username', 'password', 'a1', 'a2', 'a3'];
$attrAdmin        = ['username', 'password', 'a1', 'a2'];
$attrNormal   = ['username', 'a1'];

if(isSuperAdmin($currentUser)){
    $userInfo = User::select($attrSuperAdmin)->get();
} else if(isSuperAdmin($currentUser)){
    $userInfo = User::select($attrAdmin)->get();
} else {
    $userInfo = User::select($attrNormal)->get();
}
```

*It is pseudo code*

You will not have to hiding anythings. Just select what you want. It is a safe way.

Comment: First of all, this doesn't do what he asked. Second there is absolutely no reason to implode an array with Laravel's query builder/eloquent models.

Comment: Yeah, this doesn't do what he asked, but this touch on his goal. 'No reason to implode an array' -> agree, edited my answer